# Scripts: how to remove hex strings in a text file

Tags: regex, bash, awk

The input file is like

`<org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseClassLoader@1c7d9114,Lorg/eclipse/core/
resources/ResourcesPlugin;>.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IPluginDescriptor;)V`

the goal is to remove hex strings like `1c7d9114,`.

The length of the hex strings is fixed, that is 8.

please also include the immediate following comma.

Is there any simple script could deal with this?

Comment: Can this hex string appear anywhere in the file or do you think there is a fixed position where you would see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's/@[a-f0-9]\{8\},/@/' input
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -pe 's/\@[a-f0-9]{8},/\@/' input.txt
```

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '{gsub(/@[a-f0-9]{8},/,"@",$0)}1' input.txt
```